# Haskell dot operator with multiple parameters

Tags: haskell

I am doing exercise in fp-course
https://github.com/system-f/fp-course/blob/5e0848b4eacb3ddff65553ab5beb6447b73f61b3/src/Course/Applicative.hs#L357

The correct answer is

```
replicateA n ka = sequence $ replicate n ka
```

I cannot use (.) to do `eta reduce` as follow. Maybe because `(.)` only accept one parameter.

```
replicateA = sequence . replicate   -- wrong
```

Other example like flatMap

```
flatMap f xs = flatten $ map f xs
flatMap = flatten . map             -- wrong
```

How to use `eta reduce` when facing multiple parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to convert this function to point-free notation, you'll need to use the `(.)` infix operator twice. Let's start with what you have.

```
replicateA n ka = sequence $ replicate n ka
```

Let's write this with explicit parentheses

```
    replicateA n ka = sequence $ (replicate n) ka
```

Now this looks like function composition. Specifically, we're composing `sequence` and `(replicate n)`.

```
    replicateA n ka = sequence . replicate n $ ka
```

Now cancel off `ka`.

```
    replicateA n = sequence . replicate n
```

Now operators are really just two-argument functions, so we can rewrite this as

```
    replicateA n = (.) sequence (replicate n)
```

Again, this is function composition. We're just composing `(.) sequence` with `replicate`. So

```
    replicateA n = ((.) sequence) . replicate $ n
```

Cancel off the `n`.

```
    replicateA = ((.) sequence) . replicate
```

Now rewrite `(.) sequence` to use an operator section.

```
    replicateA = (sequence .) . replicate
```

Is this more readable than the original? No. But it's point-free now.